# Deploy node.js in hostinger VPS but not running

Tags: node.js, vps, pm2

I have my node app upload into hostinger and npm start run well.

But I still can't access http://my-ip:3000

[image: This is after I install pm2 and it's running]

node and npm and mysql have been installed

[image: trying to open my app on http://my-ip:3000]

but no luck.

Am I missing some important steps?

[image: my vps]

Answer (score 0):

this problem could come from your code || network

```
pm2 logs
```

see if there are some error logs

check on vps that if your service online

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

if no resposne, you should fix the service code

check if your service runs on the right port

```
netstat -an | grep 3000
```